# Need to show the lowest value also in graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I have used the following code to draw chart using AchartEngine in Android. The lowest value is set to the min value of x axis, even though I use multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0). I need to show the lowest value also. And also I need to remove the bar color indicator.

[image]

```
private String[] mMonth = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
            "Jun", "Jul" };
    int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int[] income = { 2000, 2400, 2500, 2700, 3000, 2800, 3500, 3700, };

    XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        incomeSeries.add(i, income[i]);     
    }
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);
    XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(207, 44, 46));
    incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(1);
    incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);

    }
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(30);
    multiRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
    multiRenderer.setGridColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
    multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));
    multiRenderer.setShowAxes(false);
    multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    int length = multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        multiRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setDisplayChartValues(false);
    }
    LinearLayout chartContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);
    mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(getBaseContext(),
            dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        chartContainer.addView(mChart);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the x axis min to something that would include the bar width entirely. For instance:

```
renderer.setXAxisMin(-0.5);
```

Comment: Dan, I did this already. I like to remove the bar color indicator, which i mentioned in the image. Could you help me for that

Comment: it came as default. If I give any string to XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Any string"); that will get displayed after the red square.

Comment: renderer.setShowLegend(false);

Comment: thanks, it works. one more thing. how to increase the default size between y axis labels. and remove the "-" present underneath the label.

Comment: I don't understand your questions.

Comment: renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT). You cannot remove the tick marks.